# Watch pom.xml file merged changes in Gerrit

Tags: git, maven-3, gerrit

I would like to get email notification by watching merged changes in `pom.xml` for maven project. When i am doing following changes in Gerrit settings, it complains server error with following error:

**Gerrit settings Watched Projects**

```
Project name - ABC (maven project name having pom.xml file)
Only if - 'branch:master file:^.*\.xml$'
```

**Error**

```
Invalid query: 'branch:master file:^.*\.xml$'

line 1:0 no viable alternative at character '''
```

`Only if` value was given by referring [link](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#watch):

Could someone please suggest how to resolve it.

Also, please suggest if multiple branches can be provided in `Only if`:

```
branch:master release/1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to query using the search box with the following:

```
(branch:master OR branch:release/1.1) AND file:"^.*\.xml$"
```

I think it should work on the watched projects too.